# Read DataTable by RowState

Tags: c#, validation

I am reading my DataTable as follow:

```
foreach ( DataRow o_DataRow in vco_DataTable.Rows )
{
//Insert More Here
}
```

It crash; because I insert more records.

How can I read my DataTable without reading the new records?  Can I read by RowState?

Thanks

Comment: What application are you using? What language?

Comment: I'm voting that this gets moved to Stack Overflow. You don't need to do anything other than have a linked account to receive the question. You can create and link the accounts later.

Comment: @RBrattas, please associate your accounts at http://stackoverflow.com/users/270429?tab=accounts, that will help you if the question is automatically moved to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what language you are using I can only give general advice.

In most (all?) languages it's not possible to do a `foreach` over a collection if you are modifying the collection. There are two common ways to deal with this.

Wild ass guessing pseudo code follows:

```
// first way uses array notation (if possible)
var no_of_rows = vco_DataTable.Rows.count();
for(var i = 0; i < no_of_rows; i++) {
  DataRow o_DataRow = vco_DataTable.Rows[i];
  //Insert More Here
}

// The second way copies the data
var my_copy = vco_DataTable.Copy()
foreach ( DataRow o_DataRow in my_copy.Rows )
{
   //Insert More into vco_DataTable Here
}
copy.Dispose() // delete/destroy the copy
```

Comment: DataTable o_DataTable_ReadOnly = vco_DataTable.Copy();

foreach ( DataRow o_DataRow in o_DataTable_ReadOnly.Rows )
{
   //Insert More into vco_DataTable Here
}